# Python: Read UTC string, output other timezone with format

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, timezone

I keep getting crazy with all of these time functions.
I have a string being in a specific format and UTC time. I want to output the time only, but in another timezone.
Thats what I have, the original one is X. I want the output to be "%M:%S" but with a different timezone. I do not want to hardcode a timedelta due to daylight saving time.

```
x = "2022-10-11T14:00:00Z"
tz = timezone("Europe/Berlin")
tz.localize(datetime.strptime(x, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ"))
```

THe localize line converts to the other timezone successfully, but I dont get it to just show the time in the end.

Comment: You need to parse the Z to UTC, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/62769371/10197418, then use `astimezone` to convert from UTC to whatever tz you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

parse Z to UTC, the use `astimezone` to convert to whatever tz you need:

option with pytz and strptime, use `%z` to parse `Z`:

```py
from datetime import datetime
import pytz

x = "2022-10-11T14:00:00Z"
dt = datetime.strptime(x, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z").astimezone(pytz.timezone("Europe/Berlin"))
print(dt)
# 2022-10-11 16:00:00+02:00
```

pytz is deprecated, so here's a ***Python 3.9+*** solution using `fromisoformat` and `zoneinfo` as an alternative:

```py
from datetime import datetime
from zoneinfo import ZoneInfo

x = "2022-10-11T14:00:00Z"
dt = datetime.fromisoformat(x.replace("Z", "+00:00")).astimezone(ZoneInfo("Europe/Berlin"))
print(dt)
# 2022-10-11 16:00:00+02:00
```

---

If you're using ***pandas***, `pd.to_datetime` will automatically parse Z to UTC, so you just have to use `.dt.tz_convert`:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'dt': ["2022-10-11T14:00:00Z"]})

df["dt"] = pd.to_datetime(df["dt"]).dt.tz_convert("Europe/Berlin")

print(df)
#                          dt
# 0 2022-10-11 16:00:00+02:00
```

Comment: The first one actually works very good. The second one gets me an error if I use that together with apply in a dataframe => 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'total_seconds', which happens in the astimezone part. I will have a look for it, thank you!

Comment: Edit: My original question was, how I then can convert that into the format %H:%S :)

Comment: So I guess you should add .strftime("%H:%M:%S") in the end so I can accept the answer as correct :)

Comment: @DORpapst it seems you're using pandas? I've added an option for this as well. Wouldn't recommend any of the two other options then.